# In browse mode, NVDA focus is going to a hidden element

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

Actual Result:
In browse mode, NVDA focus is going on hidden element 'Your dependent account has been created successfully' after 'Dismiss' link.
It has been observed that after 'Dismiss' link NVDA focus is going on hidden element and announcing info as 'Your dependent account has been created successfully'.

[image: NVDA focus is going on hidden element]

Expected result:
In browse mode, NVDA focus should not move on hidden element 'Your dependent account has been created successfully' after 'Dismiss' link.
Ex: NVDA focus should move on 'Feedback' button instead of going on hidden element 'Your dependent account has been created successfully' after 'Dismiss' link.

Comment: Lots of stuff missing from this question.  I don't see a "dismiss" link in your screenshot.  Where is that coming from?  Your screenshot of the NVDA speech output, is that output read all at once or are you arrowing down to each element?  I don't see a "feedback" button in your screenshot.  It sounds like you might have elements in the background that are getting focus because you haven't implemented the "Test" dialog correctly.  See https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialogmodal/

Comment: I assume "Dismiss" is "Close" - and it looks more like a button than a link. "Feedback" is on the right hand side of the screenshot. OP: Have you tried calling `focus()` on the "Feedback" element when the Dismiss/Close button is clicked? Agree with @slugolicious that we need to know more about the DOM to give better advice. Is the hidden element inside or outside the dialog markup? How is it being hidden?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to render your question more clear.